# How do I disable tooltips for field help text in Bootstrap?

Tags: 8, theming

On the user registration page, my help text for fields is displayed as pop-up text when I use the Bootstrap theme, but this doesn't work well on mobile devices, and most of my users are visiting through their phones.  How do I get rid of the tooltips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a setting for this.

1. admin/appearance/settings/bootstrap
2. Javascript -> **Uncheck** *Enable Bootstrap Tooltips*

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the GUI way of disabling the tooltips, there are other ways of disabling these tooltips. Following are the options that I know of.

**Option 1:** Admin interface

First and generally best way through the theme settings in the admin interface (see Patrick Kenny's answer)

**Option 2:** theme .info file

Through the `bootstrap.info` file or your own Bootstrap subtheme's info file:

```
; Tooltips
; --------------
settings[bootstrap_tooltip_enabled] = 1
settings[bootstrap_tooltip_animation] = 1
settings[bootstrap_tooltip_html] = 0
settings[bootstrap_tooltip_placement] = 'auto left'
settings[bootstrap_tooltip_selector] = ''
settings[bootstrap_tooltip_trigger]['hover'] = 'hover'
settings[bootstrap_tooltip_trigger]['focus'] = 'focus'
settings[bootstrap_tooltip_trigger]['click'] = 0
settings[bootstrap_tooltip_delay] = 0
settings[bootstrap_tooltip_container] = 'body'
```

**Option 3:** Disable tooltips per element

If you do not want to disable tooltips theme-wide, you should be able to disable them by element. You could use `hook_form_alter()` with underneath setting for most existing forms or set it directly on your form when creating it.

```
// Set #smart_description to FALSE, to disable tooltips
$form['my_element']['#smart_description'] = FALSE;
```