# Disable Bootstrap Tooltips for Individual Form

Tags: 7, forms, bootstrap-theme

Is it possible to disable bootstrap tooltips for an individual form (all the components in the form)? I know I can do it in the Bootstrap settings, which will turn off tooltips for all forms, but I only want to turn it off for one form - for all the components within that form.

I saw the answer for [How do I disable tooltips for field help text in Bootstrap?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/244245/2369) which shows how to turn it off for individual components, but I want to turn it off for the whole form.

Comment: Some JS with `$('form *[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip('disable')` attached to form should work

Comment: Thanks Oulalahakabu for your advice. I will try it out.